# How to split single cells in a CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, split, nested, clistctrl

I'm currently working on a C++/MFC Application, and I have various List controls(eg. CListCtrlStyled objects:

I need **a way to split individual rows in multiple columns**, *without* changing the cells in the same row.

[Here](http://i1141.photobucket.com/albums/n589/IT00/NesteCListCtrl.jpg) you can see the result I want to achieve.

At first, I thought to insert a list inside another, but this way it does not seem feasible ...
is there any other way to get a similar effect?
Links to external docs and/or sample code are welcome.

Thanks

IT

Comment: I'd start from a [grid control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27), or perhaps [The Ultimate Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page) control. My guess is that you don't end up splitting a single cell, but merging cells where you want fewer. Even there, they may not be truly merged -- you probably end up with invisible, zero-width cells (or it may just let you specify a different number of cells per row -- I can't remember).

Comment: You need to take over a part of the CListCtrl normal drawing operation by implementing a custom-draw subclass of the CListCtrl. Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I solved my problems simply using the UltimateGrid control. Thanks, Jerry! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

LPNMHEADER phdr = reinterpret_cast(pNMHDR);
NMLISTVIEW *pLV = (NMLISTVIEW *) pNMHDR;

pLV->iItem;
pLV->iSubItem;